# metaclass error when inheriting from psychopy.visual.DotStim

Tags: inheritance, psychopy

I'm trying to inherit a class from visual.DotStim like this

```
class JitterDots(visual.DotStim):
...
```

I always get the infamous metaclass error:

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

I understand you can fix this by merging all base classes' metaclasses, but I can't see where DotStim or its bases use any metaclasses, so I'm really confused by this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working for me:

```
from psychopy.visual import dot

class JitterDots(dot.DotStim):
    pass
```

Unrelated to your immediate question, but still a possible pitfall:
I also noticed that some of the bases/parents of `DotStim` inherit directly from `object`, but never initialize *their*  parent via `super()` -- although `super()` is called in `DotStim.__init__()`. However, "doing so will cause other classes' `__init__` methods to not be called", according to https://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

Comment: This is a consequence of the relatively new lazy-importing of visual modules (import on first use, not when visual is imported). This allows for generally faster performance most of the time.

Comment: So the missing calls to `super()` in some of the bases are not to be considered a bug, but were left out intentionally? Or were you referring to my proposed example code and its relation to Gerrit's problem only?

Comment: I think that the missing calls to super() should be fixed, that was not deliberate. But I think Gerrit's issue is due to the new use of lazy imports. When visual is imported, DotStim is not automatically imported into its name space. Its only imported there when actually used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Ok, so I need to explicitly 'import psychopy.visual.dot'. Thanks!